# Single instance of a harmonic series being less than the harmonic series multiplied by a constant such that C < 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaoJQ.png)

This was posted last year as a problem of the week for my university without a solution.
I cannot think of a single instance where this statement is true, and I don't know how to go about proving it regardless. What is a single case where this inequality holds?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a single instance; naturally if you choose $m_1>1/c$ then the statement will be true for $n=1$. Indeed you basically want to do something like this all the time. Indeed a naive idea you might come up with would be "recursively choose $m_k$ to be the smallest possible number that will make the inequality hold true". The problem is that then you probably will never see the number $1$ in the sequence at all if you do this.

Comment: (Cont.)  To avoid this problem you have to "accumulate some leeway" by choosing $m_k$ larger than necessary until you can throw $1$ into the sequence, then do that again until you can throw $2$ into the sequence and so on.

Comment: For an example of how you might proceed, say you want to have $c=1/2$. Start summing up $m_k$'s that will only ever add up to $1/4$ on the LHS, so $m_1=8,m_2=16,\dots$. Thus you have $\frac{1}{8}<1/2(1),\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}<1/2(1+1/2)$; keep doing this until the difference between the two sides exceeds, say, $2$. Then throw in $1$. Then continue taking $m_k$ to be powers of $2$ until the difference exceeds $2$ again. Then throw in $2$. And so on (skipping over $2^n$ for $n \geq 2$ as you go of course).